# How to add a data from a texbox in a variable every time it is repeated in a loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I have a problem with a test I am doing in javascript. This is my code:

```
actionField.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        var actionText = actionField.value;
        const regex = /([.@:])([^.@:]+)(?=[.@:]|$)/g;
        while ((m = regex.exec(actionText)) !== null) {
            switch (m[1]) {
                case '.':
                    console.log(´${m[2]} is 0´);
                    break;
                case '@':
                    console.log(´${m[2]} is 1´);
                    break;
                case ':':
                    // HERE IS MY PROBLEM!
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In a textbox I can enter three types of data which I can identify depending on the character they have before (`.`, `@` and `:`). The last data identified with the character `:` is a path, so more than one can exist and my text in the textbox can be seen like this:

.computer@red:products:computer:colors

My problem is that I don't know how to add all the routes in a variable and that the value of that variable can be seen in console like this:

```
products/computer/colors
```

**How can I do it?**

Comment: Put each value into an array and at the end `join('/')` it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the paths are always at the end of the string you can use a simple `split()` and `join()`

```js
let str = '.computer@red:products:computer:colors'

console.log( str.split(':').slice(1).join('/') )
```